# Inserting a document into Elastic using Alpakka

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, akka-stream, alpakka

I'm trying to learn how to use Alpakka and have setup a test to write a document to Elastic. From reading docs, including https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/elasticsearch.html have written the following :

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.alpakka.elasticsearch.scaladsl.ElasticsearchSink
import akka.stream.alpakka.elasticsearch._
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
import spray.json.{JsonFormat, _}

object AlpakkaWrite extends App{

  case class VolResult(symbol : String, vol : Double, timestamp : Long)

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()

  val connectionString = "****";
  val userName = "****"
  val password = "****"

  def constructElasticsearchParams(indexName: String, typeName: String, apiVersion: ApiVersion) =
    if (apiVersion eq ApiVersion.V5)
      ElasticsearchParams.V5(indexName, typeName)
    else if (apiVersion eq ApiVersion.V7)
      ElasticsearchParams.V7(indexName)
    else
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("API version " + apiVersion + " is not supported")

  val connectionSettings = ElasticsearchConnectionSettings
    .create(connectionString).withCredentials(userName, password)

  val sinkSettings =
   ElasticsearchWriteSettings.create(connectionSettings).withApiVersion(ApiVersion.V7);

  implicit val formatVersionTestDoc: JsonFormat[VolResult] = jsonFormat3(VolResult)

  Source(List(VolResult("test" , 1 , System.currentTimeMillis())))
    .map { message: VolResult =>
      WriteMessage.createIndexMessage("00002", message )
    }
    .log(("Error"))
   .runWith(
     ElasticsearchSink.create[VolResult](
        constructElasticsearchParams("ccy_vol_normalized", "_doc", ApiVersion.V7),
        settings = sinkSettings
      )
    )

}
```

Outputs :

```
19:15:51.815 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
19:15:52.547 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] ERROR akka.stream.alpakka.elasticsearch.impl.ElasticsearchSimpleFlowStage$StageLogic - Received error from elastic after having already processed 0 documents. Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Request failed for POST /_bulk
```

Have I defined the case class DataPayload correctly ? It does match the expected payload defined in the index mapping ? :

```
"properties": {
"timestamp": { "type": "date",
"format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
},
"vol": { "type": "float" },
"symbol": { "type": "text" }
}
```

Using Elastic dev tools the following command will insert a document successfully :

```
POST ccy_vol_normalized/_doc/
{
"timestamp": "2022-10-21T00:00:00.000Z",
"vol": 1.221,
"symbol" : "SYM"
}
```

Comment: First you should fix your logging settings as suggested by the logs you've copied: in the current state, no logs will ever be written for your app, making it almost impossible to troubleshoot further any issue. I recommend going to SLF4J link mentionned but likely you're missing an actual logging implementation like logback. Once this will be fixed, you'll get additional logs from your app.

Comment: @GaëlJ thanks, I've updated question with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works :

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.alpakka.elasticsearch._
import akka.stream.alpakka.elasticsearch.scaladsl.ElasticsearchSink
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
import spray.json.JsonFormat

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

object AlpakkaWrite extends App {
  val connectionString = "";

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  val userName = ""
  val password = ""
  val connectionSettings = ElasticsearchConnectionSettings
    .create(connectionString).withCredentials(userName, password)
  val sinkSettings =
    ElasticsearchWriteSettings.create(connectionSettings).withApiVersion(ApiVersion.V7);

  val HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60
  val utcDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - HOUR)
  val ts = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(utcDate) + "Z"

  implicit val formatVersionTestDoc: JsonFormat[VolResult] = jsonFormat3(VolResult)

  def constructElasticsearchParams(indexName: String, typeName: String, apiVersion: ApiVersion) =
    if (apiVersion eq ApiVersion.V5)
      ElasticsearchParams.V5(indexName, typeName)
    else if (apiVersion eq ApiVersion.V7)
      ElasticsearchParams.V7(indexName)
    else
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("API version " + apiVersion + " is not supported")

  case class VolResult(symbol: String, vol: Double, timestamp: String)
  println("ts : " + ts)

  Source(List(VolResult("test1", 1, ts)))
    .map { message: VolResult =>
      WriteMessage.createIndexMessage(System.currentTimeMillis().toString, message)
    }
    .log(("Error"))
    .runWith(
      ElasticsearchSink.create[VolResult](
        constructElasticsearchParams("ccy_vol_normalized", "_doc", ApiVersion.V7),
        settings = sinkSettings
      )
    )

}
```

My date format was incorrect, using :

```
  val HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60
  val utcDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - HOUR)
  val ts = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(utcDate) + "Z"
```

fixed the issue.